# Jquery: find a table row, fade out then fade in

Tags: jquery

```
function fncFadeRowIntoTable(pTable,pColumn,pValue, pHtml) {
// Add a row to a table in the correct place, by comparing the contents of the column passed (starts 0).
// This assumes that the table is already sorted
var counter = 0; // so we know when we've reached the end
//
pValue = rtrim(pValue);

$('#'+pTable).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    counter++;
    if (rtrim($(this).find('td:eq('+pColumn+')').attr('id')) == pValue) { 
    //  Have we found a cell equal to the the value passed. If so, then remove the row and replace
        var $wsRow = $(pHtml);
        $wsRow.hide();
        $(this).fadeOut(1000,function() { 
            $wsRow.insertAfter($(this)).hide();
            $(this).remove();
            $wsRow.fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'table-row');
        });
        return false; // break out of each() since we're done
    }
    if (rtrim($(this).find('td:eq('+pColumn+')').attr('id')) >= pValue) { 
    //  Have we found a cell greater than the value passed
        var $wsRow = $(pHtml);
        $wsRow.hide();
        $(this).before($wsRow);
        $wsRow.fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'table-row');
        return false; // break out of each() since we're done
    }
    // Handle case where we've reached the end, but we're still in the loop.
    // This means the new row is alphabetically last, so insert after
    if ($(this).closest('#'+pTable).find('tbody tr').length === counter ) {
        var $wsRow = $(pHtml);
        $wsRow.hide();
        $(this).after($wsRow);
        $wsRow.fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'table-row');
    }
});
// Handle empty table;
if ($('#'+pTable).find('tbody tr').size() == 0) {
        var $wsRow = $(pHtml);
        $wsRow.hide();
        $wsRow.appendTo('#'+pTable+' tbody');
        $wsRow.fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'table-row');
}
}
```

I have a function which I use to update rows in tables, based on matching the contents of a cell.  It will either insert a new row, or update the existing row.

The portion above does the replace of the row which matches.  What I want to achieve is the existing row to fade out first, then the new row to fade in.

What I'm getting is the new row being visible straight away, and then the old row fading out.  The .hide() doesn't appear to be effective, however, I know that .hide() is working when I'm inserting a row.

I've have tried the .hide() separately as 
    $wsRow.hide(); 
and also as:
    $wsRow.insertAfter($(this)).hide(); 
or as shown above, in both places.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please.

Note:
**pHtml is a complete row; i.e. "tr.../tr" data.**

Comment: I have corrected the above code in the function.  The original code had the 'return false' in the wrong place (it was in the callback function of the fadeout....).  The function allows for a row to be faded into a table by matching the id of a column to the value passed to the function.  If it matches an ID, this row gets replaced with the updated values.  Can quite easily be amended to use .html() instead of .attr('id') to match on cell contents.

Comment: As this has no real  value for other people, please delete this question of yours. (click the "delete" link above, near the "edit" etc)

Comment: @Keith, could  you make this into an answer, and accept it?  Although the actual error may not help many people, I, for one, would like to see the answer to your question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me in Chrome and IE8, existing row fades out then new row fades in - http://jsfiddle.net/x3JYz/1/.

Do you have any other code that might be interferring?